# unable to install dashing-js in linux using nodejs

Tags: node.js

i am facing issue in installing dashing-js in centos , i have followed the following steps , but i am getting the below error.[root@ip-10-0-2-15 vagrant]# npm install -g node-dashing-js
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.35.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
/usr/bin/dashing-js -> /usr/lib/node_modules/node-dashing-js/bin/dashing-js
/usr/lib
└─┬ node-dashing-js@1.0.3
  └─┬ node-sass@3.3.3
    ├─┬ meow@3.7.0
    │ └── normalize-package-data@2.3.6
    └─┬ node-gyp@3.5.0
      └── fstream@1.0.11

[root@ip-10-0-2-15 vagrant]# dashing-js new sweet_dashboard_project
: No such file or directory

Comment: i am using the following link for dashing-js https://github.com/jonnochoo/nuvo-dashing-js/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have npm global bin path included in your `PATH`.

Check PATh and where dashing-js is installed by

```
echo $PATH
which dashing-js
```

Comment: [root@ip-10-0-2-15 vagrant]# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[root@ip-10-0-2-15 vagrant]# which dashing-js
/bin/dashing-js

Comment: do dashing-js require a folder to create befor? can you try `mkdir sweet_dashboard_project` and `dashing-js new sweet_dashboard_project` again

Comment: [root@ip-10-0-2-15 vagrant]# npm config get prefix
/usr

Comment: Hi Tuan , thanks for your time , it doesnot require any folder to be created , it is working fine in windows , but when i try the same steps in linux , it is throwing error